# Calendar delete

Tags: android, calendar

I have added a new Calendar :

```
ContentValues event2= new ContentValues();          
event.put("name", "My calendar");
                    event.put("displayName", "My new calendar");
                    event.put("hidden",0);  
                            Uri url2 = getContentResolver().insert(calendarUri, event);
```

When I list all calendars , the new calendar appears but my native Calendar APP crash and now I can't the new calendar !I have searched here and I tested some ways :

```
Uri uri1=ContentUris.withAppendedId(calendarUri, calId);
  int url3 = getContentResolver().delete(uri1,"_id="+calId",projection);
  int url2 = getContentResolver().delete(calendarUri,"_id=3",projection);
```

But always shows the error: the name must no be empty :null ( the projection is a Array string with id and name)

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that you really mean 'Projection' in Delete statement? What sense does it have?
The actual signature of the method is a following: delete(Uri url, String where, String[] selectionArgs)
So maybe the problem is that you are passing projection instead of selectionArgs (which is in your case should be null, I think)?

Comment: I have tested with "null" instead of projection...but it doesn't work.Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late but :

```
Uri evuri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
//substitue your calendar id into the 0
long calid = 0; 
Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(evuri, calid);
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);
```

works for me.

Or if you don't know your calendar id :

```
Uri evuri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor result = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(evuri, new String[] {CalendarContract.Calendars._ID, CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
while (result.moveToNext()) 
{
     if(result.getString(2).equals("YOUR CALENDAR NAME"))
     {
         long calid = result.getLong(0);
         Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(evuri, calid);
         getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);
     }
}
```

Of course, finding CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME may be redundant for you so just remove it. (there's barely any overhead really)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> getContentResolver.delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI,
>   id), null, null);

Where `id` is the id of the calendar you'd like to delete.

Haven't tested it, but works for events.